# How to grep for URLs in a blog?

Tags: grep

I'm writing a script to grab the URLs from my blog posts and run `curl -I` over them so I can check they are still good. However I am having trouble writing the grep pattern.

```
<p><a href="http://example.com/fujipol/2004/may/5/16:10:47/400x345">foobar</a></p>
```

So here I want just `http://example.com/fujipol/2004/may/5/16:10:47/400x345`.

Or in markdown like:

```
[Example markdown link](https://example.com)
```

Want `https://example.com`

```
<http://example.com/?foo=bar>
```

In this case I need `http://example.com/?foo=bar`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Created file with links from your examples:

```
$> cat ./text
<p><a href="http://example.com/fujipol/2004/may/5/16:10:47/400x345">foobar</a></p>
[Example markdown link](https://example.com)
<http://example.com/?foo=bar>
<a href="http://people.debian.org/~dilinger/backports/wordpress">http://people.debian.org/~dilinger/backports/wordpress</a>
```

"Greped" it with some regular expression and got all urls from it:

```
$> grep --only-matching --perl-regexp "http(s?):\/\/[^ \"\(\)\<\>]*" ./text
http://example.com/fujipol/2004/may/5/16:10:47/400x345
https://example.com
http://example.com/?foo=bar
http://people.debian.org/~dilinger/backports/wordpress
http://people.debian.org/~dilinger/backports/wordpress
```

Done.

```
http(s?):\/\/[^ \"\(\)\<\>]*
```

What we've done here is matched `http(s)` (url could start with `http://` or `https://`), than we matched `//` and escaped it. And finally we matched sequence of symbols not equal to  or `"` or `(` or `)` or `<` or `>`.

Finally, the whole problem in tasks like that is figured out how me decide that section we needed starts (`http(s)://` in that case) and ends (, `"`, `(`, `)`, `<`, `>` ).

Frankly speaking, that solution is not really perfect. Some url standards said much more information about symbols that url can include or can't. So, at once you will figured out, that regex using in my answer is not valid. But in cases that you described it works sell.

Comment: In URLs like: `<a href="http://people.debian.org/~dilinger/backports/wordpress">http://people.debian.org/~dilinger/backports/wordpress</a>` it matches `http://people.debian.org/~dilinger/backports/wordpress` and
`http://people.debian.org/~dilinger/backports/wordpress</a`. I only want to match URLs as described above.

Comment: You should add `<` symbol to regex. So finally is `grep --only-matching --perl-regexp "http(s?):\/\/[^ \"\(\)\<\>]*" ./text`

Comment: Or you want to get only one URL from `<a href="http://people.debian.org/~dilinger/backports/wordpress">http://people.debi‌​an.org/~dilinger/backports/wordpress</a>`?